# Mysqldump in amazon using PHP

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, mysql, database-backups

I want to have a database backup our database is hosted in amazon rds. My problem in everytime i run my PHP script it generates an sql file but it is empty.

Here is my code:

```
exec("/usr/bin/mysqldump -u *username* -p *password* | gzip > /var/www/html/db-backup/testdb.sql.gz");
```

Comment: it appears you aren't specifying a database host. does this work when you run it by hand?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to specify which database you want to backup

```
exec("/usr/bin/mysqldump -u *username* -p*password* *dbname* | gzip > /var/www/html/db-backup/testdb.sql.gz");
```

and you have to specify password next to -p parameter without space (mysqldump -u youruser -pyourpassword -h yourhostname yourdatabase)